# Ошибка при запуске .py скрипта на сервере

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с ошибкой.
Из того, что я нагуглил, я понял, что скрипт не может найти драйвер. Как оказалось лежал он в другом каталоге. Я создал сам каталоги по пути, по которому на linux просит Selenium держать драйвер для Chrome, после чего ошибка не исчезла. В чём может быть проблема?

Версия драйвера: 95.0.4638.54

```
====== WebDriver manager ======
Could not get version for google-chrome with the any command: google-chrome --version || google-chrome-stable --version
Current google-chrome version is UNKNOWN
Get LATEST chromedriver version for UNKNOWN google-chrome
Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/95.0.4638.54/chromedriver] found in cache
main.py:24: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass in a Service object
  self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 261, in <module>
    p = parser()
  File "main.py", line 24, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 72, in __init__
    service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 99, in __init__
    options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 266, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 357, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 418, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x55ac9d2edf93 <unknown>
#1 0x55ac9cdc8908 <unknown>
#2 0x55ac9cdebb32 <unknown>
#3 0x55ac9cde765d <unknown>
#4 0x55ac9ce21770 <unknown>
#5 0x55ac9ce1b973 <unknown>
#6 0x55ac9cdf1df4 <unknown>
#7 0x55ac9cdf2de5 <unknown>
#8 0x55ac9d31d2be <unknown>
#9 0x55ac9d332ba0 <unknown>
#10 0x55ac9d31e215 <unknown>
#11 0x55ac9d333fe8 <unknown>
#12 0x55ac9d3129db <unknown>
#13 0x55ac9d34f218 <unknown>
#14 0x55ac9d34f398 <unknown>
#15 0x55ac9d36a6cd <unknown>
#16 0x7fa6f153e6db <unknown>
```

Часть кода:

```
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import telebot
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
import configparser
....
def __init__(self):
        self.timestamp = time.time()
        config = configparser.ConfigParser()
        config.read('config.ini')
        self.chat_id = config['BOT_SETTINGS']['chat_id']
        self.field_goal_percentage = float(config['BOT_SETTINGS']['field_goal_percentage'])
        self.field_attack_percentage = float(config['BOT_SETTINGS']['field_attack_percentage'])
        self.field_freekicks_percentage = float(config['BOT_SETTINGS']['field_freekicks_percentage'])
        self.field_dangerattacks_percentage = float(config['BOT_SETTINGS']['field_dangerattacks_percentage'])
        self.token = config['BOT_SETTINGS']['token']
        self.bot = telebot.TeleBot(self.token)
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--headless")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
        self.idss = []
        self.kof_for = float(config['BOT_SETTINGS']['kof'])
        self.iterations = 0
        with open("plays.json") as f:
            for i in json.loads(f.read()):
                self.idss.append(i)
        self.get_links()
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Добавьте инфомацию о том какую версию веб-драйвера установили по пути в который смотрит скрипт.
2. Укажите что за сервер с поддержкой графического интерфейса или нет? Помоему для линуксов без gui нужно запускать webdriver в режиме --headless, подробнее: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46929945/6622658

Comment: Добавил инфу в общий вопрос

Comment: Попробуйте убрать ошибку: 
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
, как указано здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50642308/webdriverexception-unknown-error-devtoolsactiveport-file-doesnt-exist-while-t

Comment: Не помогло, ошибка осталась прежней